# Graphic API for embedded system

Tags: c, api, graphics, embedded

I'm looking for a graphic API for embedded systems. With "graphic", I mean an API which is able to draw lines, fill areas, blit bitmaps, etc. I need something that is written in pure C (no C++).

With "embedded systems", I'm thinking of small systems where Linux is too big to run. So I would appreciate a library which is not too concerned with file systems, and OS-level access, but just exposes the graphic primitives with a C interface, and draws in memory buffers.

Any suggestion?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366278/graphics-library-for-embedded-systems-without-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Swell Software](http://www.swellsoftware.com), offers [C/PEG](http://www.swellsoftware.com/products/cpeg.php).

Here's an excerpt from the C/PEG product page:

> C/PEG is a complete graphics solution for embedded developers written entirely in ANSI C. C/PEG not only provides optimized graphics primitives, text and bitmap drawing; it also supports higher level graphic objects to give the developer a full tool set for rapid application development

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting. Any figure on the licensing cost?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have no idea what the licensing options and associated costs may be.  A quick email to *sales@swellsoftware.com* should yield the info you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We've used EasyGui - http://www.easygui.com/ - for the start of a project (it's currently on hold).

From the bit I've done it seems quite good. You design up the UI on a PC then generate the C code which makes it all happen.

One thing I like is that if you structure your app properly the code that runs the UI can be separate to the actual UI - ie it could be reused on a different screen resolution/colours/etc. We've made up a modular system where we can reuse bits in different projects as long as we follow the appropriate conventions for button numbers, etc